# Differences between "updates," "upgrade," and "version-upgrade"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The upgrade documentation at https://drupal.org/upgrade states that an **upgrade** consists of changing the major version while an **update** is changing the minor version of Drupal.

Excerpt:

> **What's the difference? Major versions (upgrade) versus Minor versions (update)**
>
> Before you start updating or upgrading your Drupal installation it is important that you know the difference between a major and a minor version release.

We know that applying updates is part of the routine maintenance tasks, whereas an upgrade is a task of a different scale, a project that presumably involves adjusting code, design, modules, etc.

Yet when tagging a question with [upgrade](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade), it gets renamed automatically to [updates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates) as they are the same thing. I assume one is set as a synonym of the other.
[version-upgrade](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-upgrade) is also suggested, and that would theoretically be fine, except that almost nobody seems to use it (3 questions only).

When searching for questions on upgrades, this confusion between tags doesn't help because questions on upgrading like [Upgrading a site from Drupal 6 to 7 using Drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78263)
get tagged the same as questions on updating like [How to get update to check Feature Server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78654).

Wouldn't it be better if they were not synonyms and their descriptions were aligned with Drupal.org's documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the tags. Now there are two tags:

- [updates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates)
- [upgrades](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades)

Upgrading a module/site is different than updating it; the first is generally a more complex operation, and often the more problematic one.
Users who answer [updates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates) questions could not be prepared to answer [upgrades](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades) questions; users who are checking if somebody had their same upgrading problem (and asked a question on *Drupal Answers*) would find questions about updating. For this reason, I re-tagged the questions that should use [upgrades](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades).

I guess that at the time the synonym was set, the two tags were used as if they were synonyms; in fact I found at least a question whose title speaks of updating, but whose text speaks of upgrading.
It seems also that [migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) gets sometimes used instead of [upgrades](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades), when the question doesn't make clear the OP migrated the site from a domain to another), but that is a different story.

I replaced [version-upgrade](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-upgrade) with [upgrades](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades), since *version upgrade* doesn't convey any specific meaning.

Now we just need volunteers who write the tag wikis for those tags.